# Alert Dialog doesnt come up

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

**Confusion**

On my emulator everything works correctly, the dialog comes up and works perfectly. However on my galxy tab running 3.0 android when I open the same app as I did on the emulator on this tablet nothing happens... What is up with that?

**Errors**

C: Error: java.net.ConnectException: /192.168.0.182:1027 - Connection refused

this error comes up once when I run my app on my tablet, but doesnt ever come up when I run it on the emulator.

**Information on the app**

On my app what is happening, there is a server hosted by a whole different thing (for CNC Machines) however only one tablet can be connected to a machine at a time, I need it so if I connect and someone is already connected to that machine an option will come up to ask if you want to disconnect the other person connected. This all works properly on the emulator but on the tablet I get an error as soon as I hit connect (where someone is already connected or not) and if someone is connected the alert dialog does not come up asking if I want to disconnect them. But it works on the emulator using the EXACT same code.

**Code**

```
public void disconnectOtherUser()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.titleTextStyle));
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to disconnect the other user?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                       Talk1028("X");
                       ConnectionTV.setText("Other user disconnected");
                       dialog.cancel();

                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
               {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                   {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

I call this method in a different spot in my code in order to make the dialog come up.

Comment: is there anything in the logcat on the device when you start the activity?

Comment: @Tim it works fine on the tablet where I could see the LogCat, but on the tablet where I no longer have access to that, this is where it doesnt work.

Comment: if you do not have access to logcat how are you pushing the apk to the device it isn't working on? also can you post the section of code where you call this method? is it possible that there is some if statement or something that could be evaluating to false for some reason on the device in question?

Comment: @MichaelZeuner turn on USB debugging and while the app is running execute the command: `adb logcat`

Comment: I have updated my question providing more information and the errors that I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. All I had to do was add a delay to the program because it was racing. However I didnt have this problem on the emulator because the emulator runs at a much slower frame rate.